# How to set default (max) value of a slicer in power bi

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a list of weeks in year.
I want to have slicer that will auto-select max value of the week for the moment.

eg. If we are in week 42 - I want my slicer by default to select that week in Power BI.

[this is how I want it to be selected by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrnkr.png)

Tried few things but did not succeed.

Please advice!

Tried f

Comment: order your data in such way(descending) so that your latest week always appears on top row. now add a slicer with "single selection" option ON and this should solve your issue.

Comment: I know that, but I need multi-select option if needed, not just single selection option unfortunately..

Comment: Then no option as per my knowledge :(

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for it to default to a week number as in your picture.

The work-around is to rename the max week in another column and use that in the slicer. Create an additional column in your date table, and replace the max week date with "Current week". Select it in the slicer and it will always default to the current week.

See [Default slicer selection (latest date) in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63480482/default-slicer-selection-latest-date-in-power-bi)

Answer (score 0):

I got it like this

```
Measure = IF(
  ISFILTERED('Table'[Week]), 
  SUM('Table'[qtd_taskers]), 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[qtd_taskers]),
    FILTER(
      'Table',
      'Table'[week] = MAXX('Table', 'Table'[week])
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new column to rename the current week, slicer of "current week" will always be the week of current day. see as attached.

[New Column]

[Slicer]

Comment: No attachment...